# How can I tune into two FM frequencies at the same time?

Tags: gnuradio

I have a file source for a FM radio capture and have a working FM tuner. I need to tune into two frequencies and listen at the same time.

Any help to accomplish this would be appreciated!

Current setup:

[image: current setup]

Comment: Is it always the same two stations, or you want a receiver that can arbitrarily tune to any two stations?

Comment: Preferrably one that can tune to any two stations.

Comment: Anything I come up with ends up being not that different than just running two receivers, any reason you can't simply do that? (A second multiplier and signal source tuned to your second station and repeat the signal chain downstream?).

Comment: yep, exactly what @DanBoschen says. But: your current signal source block doesn't make sense – a 100 MHz tone can't be represented by a 10 MHz digital signal, and will just be a constant. I think you might be confusing baseband and passband frequencies!

Comment: Tuning is not exactly a problem, you could switch your local oscollator rapidly and tune to a sampled version of both stations but to be able to demodulate the FM signal, you need to synchronise with the phase of the carrier before you start switching it and then when switching carriers switch the phase as well. Which could work if the stations are not moving or with a crafted protocol but which is also much more messy than two independent receivers.